# how to effectively convert a list to type alias in Elm

Tags: list, types, alias, elm

I have this type alias:

```
type alias ResponseLine =
     { tag : Maybe String
    , vr : Maybe String
    , value : Maybe String
    , comments : Maybe String
    , len : Maybe String
    , vm : Maybe String
    , name : Maybe String
    }
```

I Get a lot of these List Maybe String 's submatches back from regexing a Http.request text response:

```
[ Just "0008,0005"
, Just "CS"
, Just "ISO_IR100"
, Nothing
, Just "10"
, Just "1"
, Just "SpecificCharacterSet"
]
```

I need a way to go from those Lists to those type aliases. I tried:

```
getResponseLine : List Maybe String -> ResponseLine
getResponseLine =
    foldl (\arg fn -> fn arg) ResponseLine
```

While there are no errors shown at all in VSCode, reactor cannot build my app, after trying for some time it says:

```
elm-make: out of memory
```

I guess some recursive stuff is going on. So, do i need to use Array.fromList and use indexes, or is there a more functional approach i have overlooked?
The internet is too full with posts of problems the other way around :(
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert a `List` of 7 `Maybe String` values to a `ResponseLine` object, then something like the following should work:

```
getResponseLine: List (Maybe String) -> ResponseLine
getResponseLine strings =
    case strings of 
        [ tag, vr, value, comments, len, vm, name ] ->
            ResponseLine tag vr value comments len vm name

        _ ->
            Debug.crash "TODO handle errors if list doesn't have 7 items"
```

I'll leave it up to you to decide what error-handling your need if the list of `Maybe String` values doesn't have length 7.  Note also that I've declared the argument to `getResponseLine` as of type `List (Maybe String)` rather than `List Maybe String`: the compiler will interpret the latter as `List` being a type that takes two type variables with the values of the type variables being `Maybe` and `String`.

I suspect the out-of-memory error is caused while the Elm compiler is trying to figure out types in your call to `foldl`.  It looks related to [this Elm compiler bug](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1231).